# cannot import name OSRNG

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, paramiko, pycrypto

Trying to install `third parties` library in `google appengine.` All i want to do is install using `pip` then copy the folder from `site-package` to my project root `lib` folder. I did and pasted the Crypto into lib folder. then throwing below error. I wonder why is working in virtualenv not working in custom env..?

when i run `dev_appserver.py Project` Getting below error.

How can i solve this traceback error ..?

```
Traceback:
File "/home/ri/studio/project/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                     resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/home/ri/studio/project/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  338.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/home/ri/studio/project/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  366.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/home/ri/studio/project/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  361.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/home/ri/studio/project/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/home/ri/studio/engineapp/Audiotube/audiotube/urls.py" in <module>
  8. from dsp import views
File "/home/ri/studio/engineapp/Audiotube/dsp/views.py" in <module>
  72. import paramiko
File "/home/ri/studio/engineapp/Audiotube/lib/paramiko/__init__.py" in <module>
  62. from transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
File "/home/ri/studio/engineapp/Audiotube/lib/paramiko/transport.py" in <module>
  33. from paramiko import util
File "/home/ri/studio/engineapp/Audiotube/lib/paramiko/util.py" in <module>
  33. from paramiko.common import *
File "/home/ri/studio/engineapp/Audiotube/lib/paramiko/common.py" in <module>
  98. from Crypto import Random
File "/home/ri/studio/engineapp/Audiotube/lib/Crypto/Random/__init__.py" in <module>
  28. from Crypto.Random import OSRNG

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: cannot import name OSRNG
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=install+3rd+party+library+%5Bgae%5D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `pycrpto` causing that problem.

By default *Google Appengine* support **pycrypto**

```
Link here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27
```